# Does SDK 2.0 work outside of Rally?

Tags: sdk, rally

I'm trying to migrate a Rally app from SDK version 1.32 to version 2.0p.

I know that in order to run an app outside of Rally in 1.32, you simply prepend the direct server URL. However, in the 2.0p documentation, it only seems to show examples of running apps within a Custom HTML app in Rally.

Can apps in SDK v2.0p be run outside of Rally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version is 2.0rc1. It supports running apps outside of Rally with a full URL :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js"></script>
```